# conda update conda , crash

Tags: python, anaconda

Today I updated my conda using the command

```
conda update conda 
conda update --all
```

Now the problem is that no command is working which was working in the earlier version of conda. Instead I am getting the following error for ex. when I try to use Spyder:

[image]

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: error shows that it needs module `PySide` - so you have to install `PySize`. OR you will have to install C/C++ librray `Qt` which is used by `PySide`. Home page for [qt.io](https://www.qt.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fully removing conda and subsequently reinstalling it? I had similar issues when updating conda (or packages) and in some cases a full re-install solved the problem.

Comment: Even if I go for fresh start then also I get the same error!